# What payment gateway to use to allow direct transfer from customer's account to the merchant registered on my website?

Tags: payment-gateway

I am facing some problem in choosing a payment gateway that can allow direct transfer from the customer's coming to my website to the merchant's registered on my website. My website acts as a place for merchants to advertise and offer some products which can be bought on my website itself but I do not want to be involved in the payment transfer stuff, so I am looking for a way through which the customer's account can directly be debited and the merchant's account receives the money without any hassles.

Comment: What are the programming aspects of your question? If there are none, this is off-topic.

Comment: @Oded i guess stackoverflow is not only abt programming it's abt sharing knowledge that everyone has and also programmatically is n't it a great way to have such payment system that will accomplish such a thing!!

Comment: Perhaps you should read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @Oded. It isnt clear unless you're familiar with the domain, but for 'Payment Gateway' you could read 'Payment API'. I would therefore say this is an on-topic question

Answer (score 0):

PayPal handles this with relative ease.  Depending on exactly what you need to do you can use a [Payments Standard](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#wps), [Express Checkout](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec), [Payments Pro](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#wpp), [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro), or a combination of more than 1 of those to suit your needs.

For example, if you're planning on taking a cut of the payment you could use Adaptive Payments and automatically split the payment between you and the merchant, but the buyer would only see that they're paying the merchant.

If you happen to be using PHP I'd recommend using my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/overview-of-php-class-library-for-paypal/).  It makes it all very simple.